# Django - RelatedObjectDoesNotExist even after default value have been written

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have extended default User model with "phone' field.
I would like user to update their phone number after sign up.
The problem is that for new created user 'phone' object is seen as empty even after default value have been written in code.
If I want update phone number via form - I get an error :
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /phone
User has no profile.

When I check user's attributtes via admin panel I see that field has default value (111 in my case), but for some reason when I load template there is empty object error.

**models.py**:

```
# extending profile 
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=12, default=111)
```

**views.py:**

```
def update_profile(request):
    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'phone.html', {

        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

**phone.html**

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ profile_form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=12, default=111)  

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: can you show what does printing instance, show ? in save_user_profile view

Comment: i am not user if i got your request right, hope i did.
when I load template I get this in terminal - 

django.contrib.auth.models.User.profile.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check the user you are getting through request object i.e. request.user and user existing in Database with a profile. If they both are same, then you can try to run the following command:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Import models of the project app you're working upon and simulate queries in views.py. It will help in verification of the DB data being correctly accessed in Django.